# PL SQL How to put many wrappers in one package

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql

reference: [How to make a wrapper to return something other than ref cursor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4648022/how-to-make-a-wrapper-to-return-something-other-than-ref-cursor)

I've got many wrapped functions that are similar to the one below, only they return different columns of course. How can i put them all in one package. because what the examples below does is replace my wrapper package everytime.

I want to know how to remove the global declarations on top so that i can add many in the same package each with different return columns

```
create or replace package WrapperSample is

  type TResultRow is record(
     if_type         codes.cd%type
    ,number_infected Integer);

  type TResultRowList is table of TResultRow;

  function GetADedIcWarningsProv
  (
    p_hos_id in work_entity_data.hos_id%type
   ,p_date   in date
  ) return TResultRowList
    pipelined;

end WrapperSample;
/

create or replace package body WrapperSample is

  function GetADedIcWarningsProv
  (
    p_hos_id in work_entity_data.hos_id%type
   ,p_date   in date
  ) return TResultRowList
    pipelined is
    v_refcur   eOdatatypes_package.eOrefcur;
    currentRow TResultRow;
  begin
    v_refcur := YourSchema.getADedIcWarningsProv(p_hos_id, p_date);

    loop
      fetch v_refcur
        INTO currentRow;
      exit when v_refcur%NotFound;
      pipe row(currentRow);
    end loop;

    close v_refcur;

    return;
  end;

end WrapperSample;
/
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, you need to define a type for each column that is returned, and the supporting functions/stored procedures need to reference the appropriate type.  But if the data types for all the columns were the same, the same type could be used...

Comment: The datatype is not all the same. at the moment i have to create a package for each one of these above (wrappersmalples1 wrappersample2..3...) but that doesnt seem right

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you would use one record definition and one table definition per different column set.

```
create or replace package WrapperSample is

  type R_WarningsProv is record(/*...*/);

  type T_WarningsProv is table of R_WarningsProv ;

  function GetADedIcWarningsProv(/*...*/) return T_WarningsProv pipelined;

  type R_OtherFunction is record(/*...*/);

  type T_OtherFunction is table of R_OtherFunction ;

  function OtherFunction(/*...*/) return T_OtherFunction pipelined;

  /* Multiple functions can use the same types as long as 
     they share the same column definition */

  function SomeOtherFunction(/*...*/) return T_OtherFunction pipelined;

end WrapperSample;
```

Comment: @user521180: Comments/commented out details